# How to improve speed when drawing over 50k sphere with Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry

right now, I used glutSolidSphere to draw multiple sphere which is 50k+ sphere
the speed is extremely low.

Is there any method or suggestion to increase speed?

below is my code...

```
void COpenGlWnd::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    ::wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, m_hRC);
    for(int k = 0; k < m_nCountZ; k++)
    {   
        for(int j = 0; j < m_nCountY; j ++)
        {   
            for(int i = 0; i < m_nCountX; i ++)
            {
            ::glPushMatrix();
            ........
            ::glutSolidSphere(Size[i][j][k], 36, 36);
            ........
            ::glPopMatrix();
            }
        }
    }
    ::SwapBuffers(m_hDC);
}
```

For more information:
the sphere will always be in specific location, but user can use mouse to rotate and see all sphere from difference view.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a couple of suggestions:

1. Create a vertex buffer object (VBO) containing the sphere and render this instead of using glutSolidSphere.
2. Look into instancing, that is drawing many spheres with a single draw call.

The following article does almost exactly what you want: http://sol.gfxile.net/instancing.html

Comment: If the spheres are all static, which seems to be the case (written after you posted), a VBO is definitely the way to go. A collection of buffers each containing as many spheres as possible.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Hm? I'm saying pack hundreds or thousands of pregenerated and pretransformed spheres into a vertex buffer (using degenerate triangles to cross empty space), then render them all with one call.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want efficiency and are only dealing with spheres, [you can actually draw a sphere with infinite resolution using only a single quad and a shader](http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tutorial%2013.html). Basically use math to work out the sphere. Start with an untextured circle. Add depth, normals, lighting, texturing and so on.

This calculates the sphere per-pixel making it as high res as required.

Comment: Link dead. Can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20150318045337/http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tutorial%2013.html